# z-index still getting covered

Tags: html, css

I'm having a little problem with my footer showing on top of my main content window.

Trying to move the margins so the main content over laps the header by 100px an over laps the footer by 100px and renders to bottom of window.

Not really sure whats wrong could it be to do with "::before" if so is there another way to do this?

Thanks

```css
#wrapper:before {
  content: '';
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

#header {
  z-index: 1;
  height: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(../images/bg02.jpg);
  border-bottom: 10px solid #01A9DC;
}

#main {
  z-index: 2;
  margin: -100px auto -50px auto;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 400px;
}

#footer {
  z-index: 1;
  border-top: 10px solid #01A9DC;
  background: url(../images/bg02.jpg);
}

#footer:after {
  z-index: 1;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="header"> HEADER<br> </div>

  <div id="main"> MAIN CONTENT </div>

  <div id="footer"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

z-index has a lot of little tricks. I think roughly it only applies in certain situations, like positioned (`relative` or `absolute`) elements or elements with `opacity` changes. I made your example work here by adding `position: relative` to your `#main` element.

```css
#wrapper:before {
  content: '';
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

#header {
  z-index: 1;
  height: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(../images/bg02.jpg);
  border-bottom: 10px solid #01A9DC;
}

#main {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  margin: -100px auto -50px auto;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 400px;
}

#footer {
  z-index: 1;
  border-top: 10px solid #01A9DC;
  background: url(../images/bg02.jpg);
}

#footer:after {
  z-index: 1;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="header"> HEADER<br> </div>

  <div id="main"> MAIN CONTENT </div>

  <div id="footer"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Z-Index is odd. The CSS property `position` plays a large role in how z-index works.

If you add `position: relative;` to `#main` you will see the desired effect.

I would say play around with different positions and z-indexes (as well as nesting these elements) and you will quickly figure out how weird it gets.